# allocate Pool 'xyz' does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, db2

Newbie here! I am working on an app, and when i run it on my tomcat server, i get the error "allocate Pool 'xyz' does not exist". It pools data from db2 databases too. Any ideas what the error is?

Looking through forums but not finding exact reasoning.

Caused by:

> Caused by: cat.cis.tuf.server.connector.jdbc.PoolSQLException:
>   allocate Pool cdbg does not exist.

Expect the app to run, show a GUI.

Comment: Edit your question to show how you defined the pool and how you configured the data source(s) for Db2.